# ASP.NET 3.5 Web Translation - Alternatives to language resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, translation, asp.net-3.5

I'm already aware about all the benefits of using resource files when translating an ASP.NET website and implemented it in some projects. But I ended up with some inconveniences:

- The optimal structure to organize the different resource files. Trying to find the balance between too many files (e.g., 1 per page) and too few (e.g., 1 for the whole project) taking into account the reuse of tags between pages.
- The high number of resulting tags.
- Some tags are high bounded to web design and even contain HTML code.

For short text tags it's almost fine but with longer ones having HTML embedded it's a bit chaotic. Using web controls/pages per language instead of multiple tags could be a possibility?

I need to, at least, contemplate an alternative to resource files. If it's not a good option, any recommendation to deal with the above inconveniences?

Comment: In the past, I have often internationalized by having a Translations table in my database. It contains just a key and the correct text for the given language. It also has some drawbacks, obviously, like when you include full HTML into your description (try handing that to a translator ...)

Comment: I see... Thanks. So it's a quite similar solution, right? Like having a unique file. Any noteworthy benefit?

Comment: It avoids the hassle of maintaining resource files, but no noteworthy benefits. It comes down to a personal preference I guess. So no real answer or solution from me, sorry.